# Windows Backup fails - Access is Denied

Tags: windows-7, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Backup Fails](https://superuser.com/questions/294287/windows-7-backup-fails)

Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 Backup Fails](https://superuser.com/questions/294287/windows-7-backup-fails)

I use inbuilt Windows 7 backup functionality to create and store system image on my network store. Until recently it worked like a charm.

Each time I press "Back up now", it immediately fails with **"Access is denied."** message. Error code is **0x80070005**. Absolutely no additional info. I don't know what access is denied. So I've googled for several hours, read through dozens of forums, and nothing.

What is probably important is that the "Access is denied." error is reported even when the network share is not accessible, so it seems the problem starts even before any actual transfer is done.

Please, tell me if you have any idea what else to try (besides completely reinstalling the system).

#### What I have tried:

- I went through Event Log (nothing reported besides the message and code already mentioned)
- Recreating the backup job several times
- Completely purge backup settings from registry and recreate it again
- Restoring filesystem junctions
- Restarting services (and checking the services are running)
- Uninstalling new software
- Disabling antivirus
- Checking harddisk with several different antivirus for possible malware infection
- Checking harddisk for errors (including SFC /scannow)
- Recreating the network share, ensuring that correct permissions are set

but nothing works.

Comment: Perhaps the backup process doesn't have sufficient write access to the network share.

Comment: @gman: It fails the same way even when the network share is not connected. The error probably occurs BEFORE any network communication.

Comment: Yes I read that but I disagree with that conclusion based on the facts as presented.

Comment: @gman: I even tried disabling WiFi and it still fails the same way...

Comment: That again does not rule of the possibility of a permissions issue on the network share. If you don't want to pursue my postulation as a potential root cause then that is your prerogative.

Comment: @gman: I've updated the question a little. I have actually checked and the permissions are set correctly. I can use Explorer to transfer/read/write files to the network share (using the same credentials entered into the backup job).

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, because the error is actually different. My Event log shows something else.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Answers](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fanswers.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fforum%2Fwindows_7-performance%2Fbackup-error-code-0x80070005%2F1ab5a681-0c88-4b98-a2c5-635d42fc314d&ei=iy_pTvS7FcmMgwfazIDtCA&usg=AFQjCNEbxzND3m4APtjnpEbRqMV4s0rwqg&sig2=-Gxo1YU3-BBYt_1FiA4Irg) had an answer to this question.

I pasted it, exactly the way I found it below.  (If It works, I'll reformat)

"I went into control panel,administrative tools,services
Look for Block Level Backup Engine Service and right click
Select properties then logon tab
Change from local system to "this account"...browse for your username
enter your password...click apply...then ok"

Comment: Tried this and it did not work :-(  thanks, anyway.

Comment: @yoshm This question was marked as an exact duplicate of another quetstion.  Have you looked at http://superuser.com/questions/294287/windows-7-backup-fails ?